# Angular 7: how to detect changes on binded data tree?

Tags: javascript, angular, tree, angular-material

An infinite level data tree is given, binded to a child component.

```
dataTree = [ { name: 'root level', children: [{   name: 'root level
first child',   children: [...more children here...] }] } ]
```

Parent component binds this dataTree to its child.

In child component, dataTree is added to a TreeController and listed/displayed on template, and I would like to follow the changes on the binded @Input dataTree:

- if new list item was added to any level
- if any list item was removed
- if any property's value changed in any level

I have already know that KeyValue and Iterable Differ can be used for this problem, but I don't really like it in this case because I need a full tree traversal.

Another idea is to create a service which would have dataTree and the child component subscribes for changes via Subject. There are some good reason behind I don't want to use services here...

Is there any idea how can I solve this problem in a nice way?

Answer (score 0):

An approach I suggest is the definition of a getter / setter, so you can grab any changes on the target property:

```
private _dataTree: DataTree;

public get dataTree() {
  return this._dataTree;
}

@Input()
public set dataTree(dataTree: DataTree) {
// Here you can compare changes, as described on your question, and do whatever is needed
  if (this.myComparisonMethodThatDetectsMyNeedsOn(dataTree)) {
    this._dataTree = dataTree;
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. If I push a new item into tree in parent, changes are not detected by child.